# What R function sends output to a new vector?

Tags: r, xts

Suppose I have a data.frame named TLT whose last line is this:

```
           TLT.Open  TLT.Close 
2010-12-14     92.4      92.14
```

And I want to add an extra vector called TLT.BarColor so it looks like this:

```
           TLT.Open  TLT.Close  TLT.BarColor
2010-12-14     92.4      92.14       "Green"
```

Here is a function that "prints" whether it was a green or red bar day.

```
bar_color <- function(ticker) {

require("quantmod")

x <- getSymbols(ticker, auto.assign=FALSE)

open        <- x[,1]                       
close       <- x[,2]                       

last_open   <- tail(open,  n=1)            
last_close  <- tail(close, n=1)            



if       (last_open > last_close)    
           {print("Red Bar")} 

else if  (last_open < last_close)          
           {print("Green Bar")}   

 else       {print("Doji Bar")}
```

Instead of using the print() R function (which only prints to console), what R function would you use to send the output to populate a new vector?

```
super_dataframe <- cbind(TLT, apply(TLT, 1, valid_function))
```

The sample function does not work in this solution. But if the function were valid, it's output could be attached in this manner.

Comment: What's the end goal here? Are you trying to plot something? Why do you need to populate a new vector?

Comment: @Chase I was attempting to generalize my end goal to simplify the question, but I'm building a trading model where price can occupy four regions, two unambiguous and the other two ambiguous. The two ambiguous regions are resolved based on what the model was signaling yesterday. If 1, then pos = long. If 4, then pos = short. If 2 || 3, then pos = pos[-1].  Substitute the barcolor in the example with pos (position) vector that is populated based on an algorithm more complex than the barcolor algo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ticker` can't be a dataframe, but has to be a character. So with the apply you use to create your super data frame, you'll have a problem. THe following function gives the labels for different tickers.

```
bar_color <- function(ticker){
   x <- getSymbols(ticker,auto.assign=FALSE)
   n <- nrow(x)
   switch(
      sign(x[n,1]-x[n,4])+2,
      "Green Bar",
      "Doji Bar",
      "Red Bar")
}

> TLT <- c("F","QQQQ")
> cbind(TLT,sapply(TLT,bar_color))
     TLT               
F    "F"    "Green Bar"
QQQQ "QQQQ" "Red Bar"
```

If you want the labels for one ticker but different dates, then this is what you're looking for :

```
bar_color <- function(ticker){
   x <- as.data.frame(getSymbols(ticker,auto.assign=FALSE))

   x$barcolor <- sapply(
            as.numeric(sign(x[,1]-x[,4])+2),
            function(j) switch(j,"Green Bar","Doji Bar","Red Bar")
   )

   return(x)
}

> head(bar_color("F"))
           F.Open F.High F.Low F.Close F.Volume F.Adjusted  barcolor
2007-01-03   7.56   7.67  7.44    7.51 78652200       7.51   Red Bar
2007-01-04   7.56   7.72  7.43    7.70 63454900       7.70 Green Bar
2007-01-05   7.72   7.75  7.57    7.62 40562100       7.62   Red Bar
2007-01-08   7.63   7.75  7.62    7.73 48938500       7.73 Green Bar
2007-01-09   7.75   7.86  7.73    7.79 56732200       7.79 Green Bar
2007-01-10   7.79   7.79  7.67    7.73 42397100       7.73   Red Bar
```

The problem you -likely- face is the fact that getSymbols does not return you a dataframe, but an xts object. For xts there are specific methods to access and add data, and one should not expect this to behave like a data frame.

```
> X <- getSymbols("F",auto.assign=FALSE)
> class(X)
[1] "xts" "zoo"
```

Comment: The second function does exactly what I was trying to accomplish. I replaced my if - else if - else structure with the vectorized version of ifelse(<condition>, <if true>, <if false>)), but your solution takes a different way. You've introduced me to some new concepts and I can't claim I fully grasp it yet, but with some digging I will. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Milktrader: look at ?sign and ?switch. What I do here, is replace x<y, x==y and x>y by values 1,2 and 3. So when x<y, value1 (green) is returned, if x==y, value 2 is returned and so on. On your own problem you might want to look for another approach, this is just a little trick I use to have an ifelse statement with 3 possibilities.

Comment: @Milktrader: just out of curiosity, from which programming language are you coming?

Comment: I'm not a programmer by trade and have never taken a programming course, as evidenced by my questions. I appreciate your help. My autodidact approach is to familiarize with C, R and Ruby. My knowledge of each is quite sparse.

Answer (score 0):

If you changed the print statements to simply the character vector itself, e.g."Red Bar", you can add that to an existing vector such as the last row. It might be clearer code if you substituted return() for the print()'s. The only problem is that a vector needs to be of all the same mode so you would need to accept a character vector or use a one line data.frame.

```
vec <- c(TLT[NROW(TLT), ] , bar.color( "TLT") )  # a character vector

onerowdf <- cbind( TLT[NROW(TLT), ], bar.color( "TLT")) ) 
# a data.frame (aka list)
```

Comment: alright, I see how eliminating the print() function helps. Would it be better to return -1, 1 or zero, and then print out a string when needed by a different conversion function. I see your point about mixing data types in a data.frame. Ruby lets you do it, I forgot R needs a list to do it.

Comment: That depends on what you are doing with the results. Since it sounds as though you are going to be using it as an intermediate, then I would probably use a list.

Comment: @Milktrader : Come on! R let you do that as well. A data frame is nothing more than a named list where every element must have the same length. Off course, if the length of the resulting vector is not the same as that of your other variables, it doesn't work. But then I can't imagine how you would possibly want to add those together in a datasset.

Comment: @Milktrader you *can* mix types in a data.frame, but it looks like you're using an xts object.  xts objects are matrices with a time index.  You can't mix types in a matrix.